# Save all XHR responses during session

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, web-scraping

I'm browsing through the Angie's List website with my Fiddler extension open in Chrome, and after each page load, Fiddler captures an XHR response for that page (I believe it's just a pixel tracker indicating the event that I visited a new page).  I'd like to be able to capture the content of these responses automatically in a CSV file.  So for example if I run "python getXHR.py http://www.angieslist.com" I'd want my csv output file to append:

angieslist.com,http://536371345.log.optimizely.com/event?a=536371345&d=536371345&y=fal...

How can I do this?  I know Python better than other languages, but other languages are fine.  If there is a way to do this directly through Fiddler/Firebug that's fine too.

Comment: `XHR` is send by `JavaScript` and Python will not run JavaScript code when it will get page from server. Tools like `Selenium` loads page and runs JavaScript but I don't know whether it can save XHR calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [NetExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/exporting-http-tracing-data-from-firebug/) (extension for firebug) you can save all requests as JSON and then you could use Python (and module `json`) to find requests with `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`

BTW: NetExport has `Auto Export`